# What does this error mean on the Chromecast receiver error: cast.player.api.ErrorCode.NETWORK/311

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to play this live stream on the chromecast http://origin.vidibus.net/live/stream/sd-5.m3u8 and I keep getting this error `error: cast.player.api.ErrorCode.NETWORK/311`

What does that error mean? If I make the requests by hand using curl they work fine. If I play it through VLC it works fine.

I don't know how long that m3u8 will be up but this is what it looks like:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1800000,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.2"
http://144.76.202.236:8080/hls/de36/sd-5/0.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=3000000,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.2"
http://144.76.202.236:8080/hls/de36/sd-5/1.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=840000,CODECS="avc1.42001e,mp4a.40.2"
http://144.76.202.236:8080/hls/de36/sd-5/2.m3u8
```

And this is what `http://144.76.202.236:8080/hls/de36/sd-5/0.m3u8` looks like:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:370
#EXTINF:8.000000,
0-370.ts
#EXTINF:8.000000,
0-371.ts
#EXTINF:8.000000,
0-372.ts
#EXTINF:8.000000,
0-373.ts
#EXTINF:8.000000,
0-374.ts
```

Comment: I may have missed it but I couldn't see the required CORS headers in there

Comment: I'm running it through a proxy that adds the correct CORS headers. That proxy works fine for most streams on the Chromecast and for this stream on other media players.

Comment: The link you provided is through the proxy or it is not? BTW, other players may not care about CORS but Cast devices do. I am not saying the CORS is an issue, I am just saying that the links you provided don't have CORS headers and if that is what a Cast devices will see, then there is at least a CORS issue.

Comment: No, the link I provided is not through the CORS proxy. The CORS proxy has been in use since June 2014 and it works fine with most live streams, I don't think that is the issue in this case. This live stream doesn't seem to work anymore but I'm still curious what that error means specially so I can explain it to the user.

Comment: This problem also appears if you use ffmpeg and the -copy option to forward it to the local server. Only if you transcode the whole stream using ffmpeg it works, but this isn't a gold solution. Maybe the .ts files are corrupt?

Comment: @alinaddaf the stream appears to be working again with other players but still not with the chromecast.  I've tried several live stream chromecast apps that use cors proxies and none of them can cast this video.

Comment: That error code means HLS master playlist failed to load due to a network error. If you believe there is no network issues, you can open a ticket on the SDK issue tracker and provide a full log and a sample stream to reproduce the issue.